# Can't convert .iso to .img on iMac G5

Tags: macosx

So I'm trying to create a bootable USB stick in order to install Ubuntu 12.04.1 on my iMac G5 running Mac OS X 10.4.11 but whenever I try to convert the downloaded .iso file into a .img, the .img.dmg file that the terminal creates just suddenly dissapears no matter where I select the output file to be.

I tried hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o /path/to/target.img /path/to/ubuntu.iso and also hdiutil convert /path/to/ubuntu.iso -format UDRW -o /path/to/target.img but the exact same thing happens. I tried becoming root before I do all of this with sudo su but I still get the same results.

The totally weird thing is that it works perfectly with Ubuntu Minimal .iso files. Could it be that the .iso I downloaded is corrupt?

Comment: Still can't find any app to do this on Ubuntu 12.04.1 powerpc64...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got in touch with the developer of dmg2img. We're working on a fix.